# POST request of an API needs to find random pre-given contained characters form two set of characters into a third set of characters

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

So more sprcifically, this `POST` request needs to do the below procedures:

1) To find if all the characters from 2 sets of characters are contained in a third set of characters.

2) The 3 sets of characters are given/inserted as parameters in the body request

3) Caps/ or no Caps does not matter in this case. Same goes for spaces.

4) Example of an input:

```
{"testees": [ "abc", "cde" ], "subject": "acbcde"}
```

5) Example of an output:

```
{
"success": true,
"error": null,
"stack": null,
"result": true
}
```

I'm working out this API with the use of "POSTMAN".

I found some articles like this one: https://attacomsian.com/blog/ways-to-check-string-contains-substring-javascript

But still, I wasn't able to make it work.

I've tried many different things both here and with the previous POST requests I had to make.

The problems this time are:

1) The type of my input. Should it be an object? Should it be a string? I don't know.

2) But most importantly: How to check if every single character from both the 1st and 2nd set of characters is contained in the 3rd set of characters?

```
app.post("/api/contained", function (req, res) {
    var input = {
        testees: toString,
        subject: toString
    }

    input.testees = req.body.testees;
    input.subject = req.body.subject;

    var output = {
        success: false,
        error: null,
        stack: null,
        result: false
    }
    console.log("Type: " + typeof input.testees + ", Value: " + input.testees + ", Length: " + input.testees.length)
    console.log("Type: " + typeof input.subject + ", Value: " + input.subject)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The types should be as you specified them in your example.

> {"testees": [ "abc", "cde" ], "subject": "acbcde"}

`testees` as an Array with both of the sets that you are willing to check and `subject` as a String that you would like to perform the checks on.

The check mechanism should be relatively simple:

```js
    let flag = true;
    function checkSet(charsSet) {
      const chars = charsSet.split('');
      for (let i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
        const char = chars[i].toLowerCase();
        if (!input.subject.toLowerCase().includes(char)) {
          flag = false;
          break;
        }
      }
    }

    const [set1, set2] = input.testees; // Destruct both sets.
    checkSet(set1);
    // You can check if "flag" is already false here and not run the second check for better performances.
    checkSet(set2);
    if (flag) {
      // Both sets are contained inside the third set.
    } else {
      // One or more of the sets is not contained inside the third set.
    }
```

Comment: The thing is that it asks: If ALL the characters from 2 sets of characters are contained in a third set of characters.

Notice that the example gives "abc" & "cde" and the third set is "aCbcde". a C b !!
And the output says that it is "success: true". 

Which means that it checks every character from both the 1st and 2nd sets, individually, with the characters from the 3rd set.

I think it needs nested loops but I can't figure it out...

Comment: @Nikoskun Do you expect this example to work?
`abc` & `cde` and the third set is `acbde`

Notice it only includes one `c` in the third set.

Comment: The third set is equal to acbcde. 

I need it to send "result: true" when every single (individual) character from both set1 and set2 exist in set3.

Comment: Edited my code. It should now make sure all the characters in both sets exist in the third set.